# why can't OctopusDeploy restore my octobak file?

Tags: backup, octopus-deploy

I am trying to move one Octopus Deploy server from a 64bit win 2012 R2 server (machine1), to a smaller, x86 windows 2008 R2 server (machine2).

I copied the .octobak file, and MasterKey, ran the restore db, got error.

Is it even possible to restore an OctopusDeploy backup from OD v2.6.0.778 on x64 to OD 2.6.3.866 on x86?

```
2015-03-02 13:02:37.9652      1  INFO  2,497 activity logs imported successfully
2015-03-02 13:02:37.9809      1  INFO  Reading the RavenDB export file; this can take some time and may not produce much output, please wait...
2015-03-02 13:05:49.9184      1 FATAL  System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Octopus.Server.Storage.ImportExport.Importer.<Import>d__0.MoveNext() in y:\work\refs\heads\master\source\Octopus.Server\Storage\ImportExport\Importer.cs:line 65
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Octopus.Server.Commands.RestoreCommand.ImportData() in y:\work\refs\heads\master\source\Octopus.Server\Commands\RestoreCommand.cs:line 147
   at Octopus.Server.Commands.RestoreCommand.Start() in y:\work\refs\heads\master\source\Octopus.Server\Commands\RestoreCommand.cs:line 79
   at Octopus.Shared.Startup.AbstractCommand.Octopus.Shared.Startup.ICommand.Start(String[] commandLineArguments, ICommandRuntime commandRuntime, OptionSet commonOptions) in y:\work\refs\heads\master\source\Octopus.Shared\Startup\AbstractCommand.cs:line 55
   at Octopus.Shared.Startup.OctopusProgram.Start(ICommandRuntime commandRuntime) in y:\work\refs\heads\master\source\Octopus.Shared\Startup\OctopusProgram.cs:line 156
   at Octopus.Shared.Startup.ConsoleHost.Run(Action`1 start, Action shutdown) in y:\work\refs\heads\master\source\Octopus.Shared\Startup\ConsoleHost.cs:line 34
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Octopus.Server.Storage.ImportExport.Importer.<Import>d__0.MoveNext() in y:\work\refs\heads\master\source\Octopus.Server\Storage\ImportExport\Importer.cs:line 65<---
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it had restored the octobak... despite the error.
after receiving the error simply start the OD service and log-in via web UI, and you will see "performing migrations".

Thanks OD.